# How to configure prettier or eslint to put a newline after function definitions and other blocks?

Tags: javascript, eslint, prettier

Right now prettier is giving me this:

```
function _project(x, k, dim: number = -1, eps: Float = -1.0) {
  if (eps < 0) {
    if (x.dtype == torch.float32) {
      eps = 4e-3
    } else {
      eps = 1e-5
    }
  }
  maxnorm = (1 - eps) / sabs(k) ** 0.5
  maxnorm = torch.where(k.lt(0), maxnorm, k.newFull([], 1e15))
  norm = x.norm({ dim: dim, keepdim: true, p: 2 }).clampMin(1e-15)
  cond = norm > maxnorm
  projected = (x / norm) * maxnorm
  return torch.where(cond, projected, x)
}
function lambdaX(
  x: TorchTensor,
  k: TorchTensor,
  keepdim = false,
  dim = -1,
) {
  return _lambdaX(x, k, { keepdim: keepdim, dim: dim })
}
function _lambdaX(
  x: TorchTensor,
  k: TorchTensor,
  keepdim: Bool = false,
  dim: number = -1,
) {
  return (
    2 /
    (1 + k * x.pow(2).sum({ dim: dim, keepdim: keepdim })).clampMin(
      1e-15,
    )
  )
}
function inner(
  x: TorchTensor,
  u: TorchTensor,
  v: TorchTensor,
  k,
  keepdim = false,
  dim = -1,
) {
```

Is there a way to configure either prettier or eslint to put a space after some of the blocks, so it is more like this:

```
function _project(x, k, dim: number = -1, eps: Float = -1.0) {
  if (eps < 0) {
    if (x.dtype == torch.float32) {
      eps = 4e-3
    } else {
      eps = 1e-5
    }
  }
  
  maxnorm = (1 - eps) / sabs(k) ** 0.5
  maxnorm = torch.where(k.lt(0), maxnorm, k.newFull([], 1e15))
  norm = x.norm({ dim: dim, keepdim: true, p: 2 }).clampMin(1e-15)
  cond = norm > maxnorm
  projected = (x / norm) * maxnorm

  return torch.where(cond, projected, x)
}

function lambdaX(
  x: TorchTensor,
  k: TorchTensor,
  keepdim = false,
  dim = -1,
) {
  return _lambdaX(x, k, { keepdim: keepdim, dim: dim })
}

function _lambdaX(
  x: TorchTensor,
  k: TorchTensor,
  keepdim: Bool = false,
  dim: number = -1,
) {
  return (
    2 /
    (1 + k * x.pow(2).sum({ dim: dim, keepdim: keepdim })).clampMin(
      1e-15,
    )
  )
}

function inner(
  x: TorchTensor,
  u: TorchTensor,
  v: TorchTensor,
  k,
  keepdim = false,
  dim = -1,
) {
```

My prettier config currently is:

```
{
  semi: false,
  parser: 'typescript',
  trailingComma: 'all',
  singleQuote: true,
  printWidth: 72,
  tabWidth: 2,
  useTabs: false,
  arrowParens: 'avoid',
  quoteProps: 'as-needed',
  bracketSpacing: true,
  proseWrap: 'always',
  endOfLine: 'lf',
  singleAttributePerLine: true,
  importOrder: [
    '^\\w(.*)$',
    '^@(.*)$',
    '~(.*)$',
    '\\..(.*)$',
    '\\.(.*)$',
  ],
  importOrderSeparation: true,
  importOrderSortSpecifiers: true,
}
```

And I am programmatically running it like this:

```
const prettier = require('prettier')

function pretty(string) {
  return prettier.format(string, config)
}
```

What is as close as you can get to this "space between blocks" style?

Comment: Are you using Windows? You could change your `endOfLine` attribute in your prettier config to be `'crlf'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `padding-line-between-statements` rule for ESlint. You can even define multiple rules;

```js
{
    "padding-line-between-statements": [
        "error",
        { "blankLine": "always", "prev": "function", "next": "function" },
        { "blankLine": "always", "prev": "function", "next": "block" },
        { "blankLine": "always", "prev": "block", "next": "function" },
        ...
    ]
}
```

[Documentation](https://denar90.github.io/eslint.github.io/docs/rules/padding-line-between-statements)

Comment: How do I run this programmatically on a string of input, can you show that as well?

Comment: Look at [this](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/integrate/nodejs-api)

Comment: That doesn't help that much, it's still pretty complicated.

Comment: To you want to format a string or lint your project?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75227185/how-to-programmatically-run-eslint-to-prettify-file