# How to programmatically run ESLint to prettify file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

After looking at the [sparse docs](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/integrate/nodejs-api) for the ESLint Node.js API, I have this code:

```
const { ESLint } = require('eslint')
const ESLINT_CONFIG = require('../eslint.code.json')

async function lint(path) {
  // 1. Create an instance.
  const eslint = new ESLint({
    fix: true,
    overrideConfig: ESLINT_CONFIG,
    useEslintrc: false,
  })

  // 2. Lint files.
  const results = await eslint.lintFiles([path])

  // 3. Format the results.
  const formatter = await eslint.loadFormatter('stylish')
  const resultText = formatter.format(results)
  console.log(resultText)
}

lint('example.ts')
```

My project has a `.eslintrc.json`, but I want to override it completely (i.e. not use it), so I created a second one, `eslint.code.json`, which is minimal:

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module",
    "project": ["./tsconfig.json"]
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "import",
    "simple-import-sort",
    "sort-exports",
    "typescript-sort-keys",
    "sort-keys",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "extends": ["prettier", "next"],
  "rules": {
    "curly": 2,
    "@typescript-eslint/quotes": [
      "error",
      "single",
      {
        "avoidEscape": true,
        "allowTemplateLiterals": true
      }
    ],
    "padding-line-between-statements": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/padding-line-between-statements": [
      "error",
      { "blankLine": "always", "prev": "*", "next": "function" },
      { "blankLine": "always", "prev": "*", "next": "block" },
      { "blankLine": "always", "prev": "*", "next": "return" },
      { "blankLine": "always", "prev": "*", "next": "type" }
    ]
  }
}
```

My `tsconfig.json` is like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "declaration": true,
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "incremental": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "declarationMap": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

I am not sure I need to use my tsconfig at all, but there it is anyways.

So when I run it on an example file such as this:

```
function tanh(x) {
  return x.clamp(-15, 15).tanh()
}
function artanh(x: TorchTensor) {
  x = x.clamp(-1 + 1e-7, 1 - 1e-7)
  return torch
    .log(1 + x)
    .sub(torch.log(1 - x))
    .mul(0.5)
}
```

I would expect it to put a space between the two functions (because of the eslint config). Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "src"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.48.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.48.1",
    "eslint": "8.31.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.1.2",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.6.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-with-typescript": "^27.0.1",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.5.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.4",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^8.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-sort-exports": "^0.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-sort-keys": "^2.3.5",
    "eslint-plugin-typescript-sort-keys": "^2.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.8.2"
  }
}
```

I am getting this error though:

```
node:internal/errors:491
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: Failed to load plugin '@typescript-eslint' declared in 'CLIOptions': The argument 'filename' must be a file URL object, file URL string, or absolute path string. Received ''
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:400:5)
    at createRequire (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1333:13)
    at Object.resolve (/exampleproj/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/dist/eslintrc.cjs:2325:16)
    at ModuleResolver.resolve (/exampleproj/node_modules/@rushstack/eslint-patch/lib/modern-module-resolution.js:210:48)
    at ConfigArrayFactory._loadPlugin (/exampleproj/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/dist/eslintrc.cjs:3392:33)
    at ConfigArrayFactory._loadPlugin (/exampleproj/node_modules/@rushstack/eslint-patch/lib/modern-module-resolution.js:219:43)
    at /exampleproj/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/dist/eslintrc.cjs:3283:33
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at ConfigArrayFactory._loadPlugins (/exampleproj/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/dist/eslintrc.cjs:3279:22)
    at ConfigArrayFactory._normalizeObjectConfigDataBody (/exampleproj/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/dist/eslintrc.cjs:3079:44) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE'
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I simply format a string? Basically these are my related questions:

- What am I doing wrong?
- Am I setting the config correctly?
- What is `stylish`, I couldn't figure out what I need to set for that? (prettier?)

Comment: It's a CLI tool, so just run it with the auto-fix option `--fix`

Comment: I am trying to do this as part of a library project, so would like to do it programmatically.

Comment: `stylish` is ESlint's built-in formatter: described [here](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/formatters/)

Comment: Try adding `plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended` to `extends` in your ESLint config.